# Create Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS autoinstall USB install device

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, 22.04, usb-installation

I want to create a USB device that I can plugin to computers to install Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS with some generic config for the startup questions (e.g. Keyboard layout, users and password, etc.). I found out that there is a feature called: [Autoinstall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart) I followed the provided steps and I'm able to boot in my machine separate ubuntu with the set config, but sadly I don't understand how I can bring this now as an ISO to a USB drive? Do I need to convert the truncated .img file to an ISO or how can I bring it to a USB drive and use it as an installable device?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Are you not sure how to create a bootable USB from an ISO? It's the same as if you were creating typical installation media. There are tutorials for Ubuntu, Windows and Mac: https://ubuntu.com/search?q=Create+bootable+usb I suggest balenaEtcher

Comment: I know how to get the iso to usb. But after following the steps in the link I just end up with an .img files (no iso which contains the autoinstall settings and Ubuntu server). I tried to flash that to usb with Rufus, but it’s not bootable or installable.

Comment: Etcher claims to support IMG files. Did you try it?

Comment: Only tried it with Rufus but I will try